# Google Translate API works in debug mode but crashes on Signed Released APK

Tags: android, google-translate

The translation works fine when I run it from an emulator and debug APK, however, the signed released APK will crash and give me this error message:

```
 Caused by: c.h.b.a.b.a.b: 403 Forbidden
    {
      "e" : 0,
      "code" : 403,
      "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
      "errors" : [ {
        "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain" : "global",
        "reason" : "forbidden"
      } ],
      "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
```

Here's my code to do the translation.

```
 TranslateOptions options = TranslateOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setApiKey(API_KEY)
                    .build();

            if (options != null) {
                Translate translate = options.getService();
                // Translates some text
                translation =
                        translate.translate(
                                inputString,
                                Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(sourceLanguage),
                                Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(targetLanguage));

            }
```

And here's my Gradle imports:

```
  implementation  ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.21.0'){
        exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'grpc-all'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
        exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-appengine'
        exclude group: 'com.google.api.grpc', module: 'proto-google-common-protos'

    }
```

Comment: open the project structure and see there will be some file containing the Api key which you set programatically, it should be inside the debug folder. Just copy that paste it into the release folder as well. Problem will be solved atleast I did it like this and worked for me

Comment: @kunalmanocha I am sorry but I don't see any folder stating `debug` and `release` folder. There is credentials where I can generate a new API key and do modifications.